# Pandas simple correlation of two grouped DataFrame columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, correlation, pandas-groupby

Is there a good way to get the simple correlation of two grouped DataFrame columns?

It seems like no matter what the pandas `.corr()` functions want to return a correlation matrix.  E.g.,

```
i = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A','B','C'], np.arange(1, 11, 1)], names=['Name','Num'])
test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(30, 2), i, columns=['X', 'Y'])
test.groupby(['Name'])['X','Y'].corr()
```

returns

```
               X         Y
Name                      
A    X  1.000000  0.152663
     Y  0.152663  1.000000
B    X  1.000000 -0.155113
     Y -0.155113  1.000000
C    X  1.000000  0.214197
     Y  0.214197  1.000000
```

But clearly I am only interested in the off-diagonal term.  And it seems kludgy to calculate the four values and then try to select the one I want, as in

```
test.groupby(['Name'])['X','Y'].corr().ix[0::2,'Y']
```

to get

```
A     X    0.152663
B     X   -0.155113
C     X    0.214197
```

Comment: How is the performance of `test.groupby('Name').apply(lambda df: df['X'].corr(df['Y']))` on your bigger DataFrame?

Comment: @ayhan: Excellent – twice as fast as the kludge in my question!  (And less kludgy ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect something like `test.groupby('Name')['X'].corr('Y')` to work but it doesn't and when you pass the Series itself (`test['Y']`) it becomes slower. At this point it seems apply is the best option:

```
test.groupby('Name').apply(lambda df: df['X'].corr(df['Y']))
Out: 
Name
A   -0.484955
B    0.520701
C    0.120879
dtype: float64
```

This iterates over each group and applies Series.corr in each grouped DataFrame. The differences arise from not setting a random seed.

Comment: That achieves the formatting result I want, but for some reason **it takes almost 100 times as long** as the kludgy version in my question to run on a large DataFrame!